# MongoDB VS Fetching Large number of Documents

Tags: java

I currently use a relational database (Oracle) and I'm experimenting with MongoDB at the moment.

I'm using the Java Driver to query and fetch data from a local instance of    MongoDB. A sample code is as such:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

MongoCollection<Document> restoCollection = db.getCollection("restaurants");

Document irishCuisineFilter = new Document("cuisine", "Irish");
FindIterable<Document> iterable = restoCollection.find(irishCuisineFilter);

iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document)  {
        System.out.println(document);
    }
});
```

The total number of documents in the "restaurants" collection is 1343082. The find query eventually yields 71918.

My initial assumption was that the above would be extremely fast. However, the forEach loop is taking around 16 seconds to complete. This defied the purpose of why I'm switching to MongoDB in the first place. I wanted something that would enable both data querying and fetching to be really fast. Is that a wrong assumption? Am I missing something?

Comment: could you please try the same thing without system.out.println() call and calculate the time in for loop?

Comment: @newbieee Already tried that. The loop itself is taking around 16 sec. The bottleneck is not from printing the document, it's the loop itself. That's what I dont understand

Comment: maybe you can try setting an index on cuisine field

Comment: Have tried instead `db.getCollection("restaurants").find(eq("cuisine", "Irish"));` ( From : https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/query/ ) ?

Comment: @Fildor Yes. No difference!

Comment: System I/O could be a bottleneck. What are you going to do with your docs? Maybe try the loop with only incrementing a counter. I guess that should be faster than 16 secs.

Comment: I confirm, I am having the same issue. I need to fetch around 10M records (2 integer properties and 3 strings with max 100 chars) and it's taking around 1m to read them all on a GB network. I dump-ed all the read-docs in bson format on disk and the size was 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

**Question : MongoDB VS Fetching Large number of Documents**

**Solution:  Indexing**

In addition to improving the code efficiency, we should also improve MongoDB read efficiency for handling large data. Although the total number of records mentioned(1343082) is not so huge, Indexing your MongoDB will improve the querying speed.

> Indexes support the efficient resolution of queries. Without indexes, MongoDB must scan every document of a collection to select those documents that match the query statement. This scan is highly inefficient and require the mongodb to process a large volume of data.

Documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/

Comment: I created an index on the cuisine field but it's still as slow it was. As a side not, when i issue the count() method on the MonogoCollection i get the number of filtered items. So it seems the filtering is fast but going over the documents is slow